# I need help performing a complicated transpose

Tags: microsoft-excel, transpose

I have a list of items in a column, i need to transpose them to horizontal. I need a1 in b1 and a2 in c1 and a3 in d1, then a4 in b2 and a5 in c2 and a6 in d2 and so forth.

[image: Excel Layout]

Comment: I think you can use Power Query and add a column with list 1,2,3,1,2,3... then translate to row.

Comment: @Lee Why not post that as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

If your version of Excel supports dynamic arrays, you can use this in cell C2:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$10,SEQUENCE(3,3))
```

The call to `SEQUENCE` creates a 3x3 grid of integers. Using this as the row parameter of index causes the correct value to be returned from the list of colors.

[image]

Comment: +1 Simple and very effective